# Let the user create a custom format using a string

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'd like a user to be able to create a custom format in `QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()` and it would format the string and split out the results in another `QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()`.

**For example**:

```
movie = {
    "Title":"The Shawshank Redemption",
    "Year":"1994",
    "Rated":"R",
    "Released":"14 Oct 1994",
    "Runtime":"142 min",
    "Genre":"Drama",
    "Director":"Frank Darabont",
    "Writer":"Stephen King (short story \"Rita Hayworth and Shawshank Redemption\"),Frank Darabont (screenplay)",
    "Actors":"Tim Robbins, Morgan Freeman, Bob Gunton, William Sadler",
    "Plot":"Two imprisoned men bond over a number of years, finding solace and eventual redemption through acts of common decency.",
    "Language":"English",
    "Country":"USA",
    "Awards":"Nominated for 7 Oscars. Another 21 wins & 36 nominations.",
    "Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMDFkYTc0MGEtZmNhMC00ZDIzLWFmNTEtODM1ZmRlYWMwMWFmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Ratings":  [
                    {
                        "Source":"Internet Movie Database",
                        "Value":"9.3/10"
                    },
                    {
                        "Source":"Rotten Tomatoes",
                        "Value":"91%"
                    },
                    {
                        "Source":"Metacritic",
                        "Value":"80/100"
                    }
                ],
    "Metascore":"80",
    "imdbRating":"9.3",
    "imdbVotes":"2,367,380",
    "imdbID":"tt0111161",
    "Type":"movie",
    "DVD":"15 Aug 2008",
    "BoxOffice":"$28,699,976",
    "Production":"Columbia Pictures, Castle Rock Entertainment",
    "Website":"N/A"
}

custom_format = '[ {Title} | ⌚ {Runtime} | ⭐ {Genre} |  {Released} | {Rated} ]'.format(Title=movie['Title'], Runtime=movie['Runtime'], Genre=movie['Genre'],Released=movie['Released'],Rated=movie['Rated'])

print(custom_format)
```

This code above, would easily print `[ The Shawshank Redemption | ⌚ 142 min | ⭐ Drama |  14 Oct 1994 | R ]`.

However, if I change this code from:

```
custom_format = '[ {Title} | ⌚ {Runtime} | ⭐ {Genre} |  {Released} | {Rated} ]'.format(Title=movie['Title'], Runtime=movie['Runtime'], Genre=movie['Genre'],Released=movie['Released'],Rated=movie['Rated'])
```

To:

```
custom_format = "'[ {Title} | ⌚ {Runtime} | ⭐ {Genre} |  {Released} | {Rated} ]'.format(Title=movie['Title'], Runtime=movie['Runtime'], Genre=movie['Genre'],Released=movie['Released'],Rated=movie['Rated'])"
```

Notice, that the whole thing is wrapped in "". Therefor its a string. Now doing this will not print out the format that I want.
The reason I wrapped it in "" is because when I add my original `custom_format` into a `QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()`, it converts it into a string it wont format later on.

So my original idea was, the user creates a custom format for themselves in a `QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()`. Then I copy that format, open a  new window wher the movie json variable is contained and paste the format into another `QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()` where it would hopefuly show it formatted correctly.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

## ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

User creates their format inside `QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()`.

[image: This is where user adds their custom format]

Then the user clicks `Test Format` which should display `[ The Shawshank Redemption | ⌚ 142 min | ⭐ Drama |  14 Oct 1994 | R ]` but instead it displays

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to use the full format command would require an `eval()`, which is normally considered not only bad practice, but also a serious security issue, especially when the input argument is completely set by the user.

Since the fields are known, I see little point in providing the *whole* format line, and it is better to parse the format string looking for keywords, then use keyword lookup to create the output.

```
class Formatter(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.formatBase = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(
            '[ {Title} | ⌚ {Runtime} | ⭐ {Genre} |  {Released} | {Rated} ]')
        self.formatOutput = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.formatBase)
        layout.addWidget(self.formatOutput)
        self.formatBase.textChanged.connect(self.processFormat)
        self.processFormat()

    def processFormat(self):
        format_str = self.formatBase.toPlainText()
        # escape double braces
        clean = re.sub('{{', '', re.sub('}}', '', format_str))
        # capture keyword arguments
        tokens = re.split(r'\{(.*?)\}', clean)
        keywords = tokens[1::2]
        try:
            # build the dictionary with given arguments, unrecognized keywords
            # are just printed back in the {key} form, in order let the
            # user know that the key wasn't valid;
            values = {k:movie.get(k, '{{{}}}'.format(k)) for k in keywords}
            self.formatOutput.setPlainText(format_str.format(**values))
        except (ValueError, KeyError):
            # exception for unmatching braces
            pass
```

Comment: Hi musicamante. Wow, I was able to implement this and it works great! However, I dont fully understand line 21, 22. If you could edit your answer and explain it that would be awesome!

Comment: I don't know what lines you're referring to, please refer their contents.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. ```values = {k:movie.get(k, '') for k in keywords}``` and ```self.formatOutput.setPlainText(format_str.format(**values)``` "**values". However, after looking into it, I do understand whats going on now. Had  to check regex checker too xD. Its really smart and Im loving it.

Comment: @J.Hasmukhlal the first creates a dictionary using *all* the keys found in `format_str`, `movie.get(k, '')` returns an empty string if the user tried to create an unexistent key in `movie` (eg: `titel`); you could even use `movie.get(k, k)` so that the wrong keyword gets shown (actually, this would be better); then `format(**values)` is used to map the values (which is a dict) for format, which is a standard function that accept keyword arguments.

Comment: @J.Hasmukhlal I updated the code, now it shows invalid keys as the source, so if the format string has `{someUnknownKey}`, it will print '{someUnknownKey}'. I also added a simple check for brace escaping (so that you can actually display braces by using `{{` and `}}`).

Comment: Thanks for the update. Currently that's not needed for me, but would certainly be usefull in the future or anyone else looking for do anything similar. Appreciate all the help musicamante.